# Ruby Geocoder how to set a minimum .near distance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geocoding

Using Alex Reisner's [Ruby Geocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) and finding the .near method very useful. One question we have is how can we set it so that we can search for objects between distance x and distance y from the origin (at the moment the .near method only sets the max distance it seems):
[documentation here](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder)

We're looking for something like:

```
places = Place.near("Washington", min_distance, max_distance).reorder("score")
```

or some way of modifying the query so that we get the same effect without using .reorder (which we're using to sort on another "score" field)

The end result we want is the ability to have places ordered by score which are between x and y miles from the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it is not natively implemented.

If using ActiveRecord, you can try to use Geocoder's [private class methods](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/d35b9d7b5e5797550496b5ec27229212cc0bf019/lib/geocoder/stores/active_record.rb) (see from line 105 to 147) to roll your own "reverse" method, with an algorithm that should be more or less :

- calculate bounding box for mininum distance query with `Geocoder::Calculations#bounding_box`
- build SQL to find all records in bounding box AND with `#distance_sql(lat,lon,options)` >= min_distance

stuff this logic inside a `where` scope, chain it to `near`, and voilà! If you feel lazy you can even just copy/paste the whole method and just change the `<=` predicate.

On a side note, it would be great to file a feature request at geocoder's github, as i think it would be quick to implement for them.

Comment: thanks - good suggestions. i've never hacked gem code before - does it get deployed to production with your regular code (heroku) - or do i need to do something special?

Comment: i wouldn't hack the gem itself, just reopen the right modules / classes in your own code. A simple way to do this is to create some files in /lib and require them in an initializer. If you want to be extra clean, create your own gem and make it depend on geocoder.

Answer (score 1):

The query generated by Geocoder includes a `distance` column so all you need to do is add a condition for the minimum distance, for example:

```
Venue.near("Washington", max_distance).having("distance >= ?", min_distance)
```

Note that you need to use `HAVING`, not `WHERE`.