# Rails Geocoder how to set a minimum and maximum near distance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geocoding

I am getting a no distance column error on the following query

```
@crimes = Crime.near(params[:location], 0.5).having("distance >= ?", 0.25)
```

As mentioned in this previous post ([Ruby Geocoder how to set a minimum .near distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624669/ruby-geocoder-how-to-set-a-minimum-near-distance)) the Gecode query generates a distance column, anything that I am missing here, work arounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work around solution.

The geocoder query returns a geocoder object. This geocoder object has a distance method that returns the distance from the .near methods location argument.

Therefore I used ruby to filter these objects out.

```
@crimes.keep_if{|crime| crime.distance.to_f >= 0.25}
```

Hope this helps!